# How to implement a singleton with async initialisation and null safety in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, singleton, dart-null-safety

I need a Singleton for the shared preferences which has async initialisation but also works with null safety. Usually I used the following singleton implementation, but what is the best way to have a singleton which works with null safety?

```
class SharedPrefs {
static SharedPrefs _instance;
static Future<Null> _mutex;

static Future<SharedPrefs> getInstance() async {
  if (_mutex != null) {
    await _mutex;
  }
  var completer = Completer<Null>();
  _mutex = completer.future;

  if (_instance == null) {
    _instance = SharedPrefs();
    await _instance.init();
  }

  completer.complete();
  _mutex = null;

  return _instance;
}

SharedPreferences prefs;

SharedPrefs();

Future<SharedPrefs> init() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return this;
}

dynamic get(String key) {
  return prefs.getString(key);
}

Future<bool> put(String key, dynamic value) async {
  return await prefs.setString(key,value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class SharedPreferencesProvider {
  static SharedPreferencesProvider? _instance;
  final SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  static Future<SharedPreferencesProvider> getInstance() async {
    if (_instance == null) {
      final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _instance = SharedPreferencesProvider._(sharedPreferences);
    }
    return _instance!;
  }

  SharedPreferencesProvider._(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences)
      : _sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
```

Answer (score 3):

### init-first singleton

```
class Singleton {
  late Map<String,String> obj;

  Db._();
  static Db? _instance;
  static Db get inst => _instance ??= Db._();
  init () async {
    // await ...
    obj = {'a': 1};
  }
}

void main () async {
  // put init first
  await Db.inst.init();

  // your other code
  // your other code

  print(Db.inst.obj);

  // your other code
  // your other code


}
```

I use this method in all languages which is stable and easy to understand.

### A tested example

db.dart

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' as Mongo;

class Db {
  late Mongo.DbCollection test;

  Db._();
  static Db? _instance;
  static Db get inst => _instance ??= Db._();
  init () async {
    var db = Mongo.Db("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
    await db.open();
    test = db.collection('test');
  }
}
```

test.dart

```
import 'package:mj_desk_server/db.dart';

void main () async {
  
  await Db.inst.init();
  
  myApp();
}

myApp () async {
  // do anything
  // do anything
  // do anything
  print(await Db.inst.test.find().toList());
  print('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70456416/3667647) works when there are two calls to `SharedPreferencesProvider.getInstances()` back to back

The following code should work no matter how many back to back calls the `getInstance()` method gets, and how much ever time the creation takes

```dart
class SharedPreferencesProvider {
  static SharedPreferences? _backingFieldPrefs;
  static Future<SharedPreferences>? _prefsFuture;

  static Future<SharedPreferences> getInstance() async {
    if (_backingFieldPrefs != null) {
      return _backingFieldPrefs!;
    }

    _prefsFuture ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _backingFieldPrefs ??= await _prefsFuture!;
    return _backingFieldPrefs!;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution (and safe at the same time) caches the Future in a static final attribute. No need for any nullable class attributes at all.

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SharedPreferencesProvider {
  static final _instance = () async {
    final sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return SharedPreferencesProvider._(sp);
  }();

  static Future<SharedPreferencesProvider> getInstance() => _instance;

  const SharedPreferencesProvider._(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences)
      : _sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
  
  final SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea but not quite there yet: you can't access `_sharedPreferences` from the outside, so it's not really useable like this. A solution would be to make it public: `final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;`. And then, you can even simplify the private constructor with an initializing formal: `const SharedPreferencesProvider._(this.sharedPreferences);`

Comment: @Gábor right, it was not a complete example and you'd also have methods like `dynamic get(String key)`, as in the code in the original question. Otherwise you could just use `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` directly.