# Async assign in Singleton in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

My code:

```dart
class SingletonSystem {
  late String name;

  factory SingletonSystem() => _instance;

  SingletonSystem._internal() {
    _setup();
  }

  static final SingletonSystem _instance = SingletonSystem._internal();

  Future<void> _setup() async {
    name = await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      return 'iOS';
    });
  }
}
```

use:

```
print(SingletonSystem().name);
```

It's null first time call `.name`, but I want `iOS` in fact.

Any way can do this **without change the code** `print(SingletonSystem().name)`?

I had check:

- [Calling an async method from a constructor in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933801/calling-an-async-method-from-a-constructor-in-dart)
- [How to implement a singleton with async initialisation and null safety in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456391/how-to-implement-a-singleton-with-async-initialisation-and-null-safety-in-dart)

Both of them can't satisfy my needs.

Show me your code if you can.

Comment: Is there a reason to use such an anti-pattern? I'm sure there are a dozen better alternatives to Singleton that will do what you want.

Comment: Also, while I personally think it's not a good idea, the second link seems to satisfy your needs just fine. Can you explain what you tried and what problems you had with it?

Comment: @nvoigt I just want the usage of this singleton simplest. Don't need to write await and don't know need to setup outside. All will be done internal and just use directly.

Comment: @nvoigt It's not common pattern and maybe can't realize.

Comment: Then I am afraid what you want is not possible. Since your example is a made up abritrary thing, is this is trick question for a quiz?

Comment: You can call SingletonSystem(); await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds :1)); in runApp.

Comment: @Rahul That would require that callers know implementation details about `SingletonSystem`.  Not a good idea.

Comment: I mean he doesn't want to change code inside singleton. If nothing changes outside, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your singleton needs to be initialized asynchronously.  There is no way to completely avoid changing the calling code since callers need *some* way to wait for that initialization to complete.  Dart does not provided a supported way to make asynchronous code synchronous.

The least intrusive change to callers would be to provide an explicit, asynchronous initialization step that callers must perform in advance.  You could, for example, change `_setup` to be public.  Since this is a singleton, `_setup` also might as well be `static`:

```dart
class SingletonSystem {
  late String name;

  factory SingletonSystem() => _instance;

  SingletonSystem._internal();

  static final SingletonSystem _instance = SingletonSystem._internal();

  static Future<void> setup() async {
    _instance.name = await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      return 'iOS';
    });
  }
}

void main() async {
  await SingletonSystem.setup();

  // ...
}
```

Note that this comes at the cost of being more error-prone since callers might neglect to perform that extra initialization step.

Comment: Thanks for your share. But why `setup` should be `static`? What's the disadvantage if not use `static`?

Comment: @无夜之星辰 See [Is it better to mark a method as static when possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75507682/).  It doesn't *have* to be `static`.  It could be an instance method, but IMO it would look weirder, and callers would be more likely to call `setup()` unnecessarily.  For example: `SingletonSystem.setup()` *looks* like a one-time initialization step, whereas  `SingletonSystem().setup()` looks like something that might need to be done every time someone calls the `SingletonSystem` constructor.  And conversely: why *shouldn't* `setup` be `static`?